# How to remove duplicate days with multiple tickers in a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Imagine I have a dataframe that contains minute data for different symbols:

```
                   timestamp  open  high   low  close  volume  trade_count      vwap symbol  volume_10_day
0     2022-09-26 08:20:00+00:00  1.58  1.59  1.34   1.34     972           15  1.433220    ADA      2889145.1
1     2022-09-26 08:25:00+00:00  1.45  1.66  1.41   1.66    3778           25  1.551821    ADA      2889145.1
2     2022-09-26 08:30:00+00:00  1.70  1.70  1.39   1.47   13683           59  1.499826    ADA      2889145.1
3     2022-09-26 08:35:00+00:00  1.43  1.50  1.37   1.37    3627           10  1.406485    ADA      2889145.1
4     2022-09-26 08:40:00+00:00  1.40  1.44  1.40   1.44    1352            9  1.408365    ADA      2889145.1
--
100     2022-09-26 08:20:00+00:00  1.58  1.59  1.34   1.34     972           15  1.433220    ADD      2889145.1
101     2022-09-26 08:25:00+00:00  1.45  1.66  1.41   1.66    3778           25  1.551821    ADD      2889145.1
102     2022-09-26 08:30:00+00:00  1.70  1.70  1.39   1.47   13683           59  1.499826    ADD      2889145.1
103     2022-09-26 08:35:00+00:00  1.43  1.50  1.37   1.37    3627           10  1.406485    ADD      2889145.1
104     2022-09-26 08:40:00+00:00  1.40  1.44  1.40   1.44    1352            9  1.408365    ADD      2889145.1
```

I want to be able to filter the list, so that it only returns a single dataframe with multiple days, but that no days are repeated (like in the example above where ADA and ADD both appear for the date 2022-09-26).

How can I filter out duplicate days like this? I don't care how it's done - it could be just keeping whatever symbol appears first for a given date, like this for example:

```
                      timestamp  open  high   low  close  volume  trade_count      vwap symbol  volume_10_day
0     2022-09-26 08:20:00+00:00  1.58  1.59  1.34   1.34     972           15  1.433220    ADA      2889145.1
1     2022-09-26 08:25:00+00:00  1.45  1.66  1.41   1.66    3778           25  1.551821    ADA      2889145.1
2     2022-09-26 08:30:00+00:00  1.70  1.70  1.39   1.47   13683           59  1.499826    ADA      2889145.1
3     2022-09-26 08:35:00+00:00  1.43  1.50  1.37   1.37    3627           10  1.406485    ADA      2889145.1
4     2022-09-26 08:40:00+00:00  1.40  1.44  1.40   1.44    1352            9  1.408365    ADA      2889145.1
--
100     2022-09-27 08:20:00+00:00  1.58  1.59  1.34   1.34     972           15  1.433220    ADB      2889145.1
101     2022-09-27 08:25:00+00:00  1.45  1.66  1.41   1.66    3778           25  1.551821    ADB      2889145.1
102     2022-09-27 08:30:00+00:00  1.70  1.70  1.39   1.47   13683           59  1.499826    ADB      2889145.1
103     2022-09-27 08:35:00+00:00  1.43  1.50  1.37   1.37    3627           10  1.406485    ADB      2889145.1
104     2022-09-27 08:40:00+00:00  1.40  1.44  1.40   1.44    1352            9  1.408365    ADB      2889145.1
```

How can I achieve this?

Update, tried drop_duplicates as suggested by Lukas, like so:

Read from db in a df:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from ohlc_minutes", conn)
```

Get the length (4769):

```
print(len(df))
```

And then:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']) 
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['symbol', 'timestamp'])
print(len(df))
```

But it returns the same length.

How can I get my drop_duplicates to work with minute data?

Comment: Have you considered having two separate intial data frames with ADD and ADA, filtering what is necessary and then mergeing the two?

Comment: Can you give a simple example to show what you mean please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pd.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['timestamp', 'symbol'])
```

By default, it will take the first appearance of the combination of the values in the `timestamp` and `symbol` columns, but you can change this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Lukas! But this seems to just return the same length array. I'm aware of drop_duplicates, but not sure how it works when you have minute data. I'll update OP to show what I mean